# I am thinking about the sentence you wrote

Tags: grammar, translation

A wonderful lady texted me a nice sentence yesterday.

> 생각해서 생각이 나온다.

Which seems to translate as "thoughts lead to more thought". As I've been thinking about this sentence since yesterday I want to reply now:

> I have been thinking about this sentence you wrote.

I have two attempts

> 1. 저는 이 당신이 쓴 문장을 생각해 와요.
> 2. 저는 이 당신이 쓴 문장에 대해 생각하고 있어요.

Then I would directly quoting the sentence. Among the two translation, which both look sensible to me the first one is the one I would prefer.

According to my grammar references the pattern 아/어/해 오다 denotes an action started in the past and carried out continuously. The first sentence would denote that I started thinking about that sentence since it was texted to me. The second one instead is conveys more the "now I am thinking about it".

Which one is more correct? If none is correct what is a better way to convey the message?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest:

> 그 동안 ~님이 쓰신 이 문장에 대해 많은 생각을 해보았어요. Since then I have been thinking a lot about this sentence you wrote.

Your comments on grammar behind "아/어/해 오다" and "하고 있다" is correct and it is grammatically correct to say:

> 당신이 쓰신 이 문장에 대해 생각해 왔어요. I have been thinking about this sentence you wrote.

But this can sound less natural to native Koreans.

It is more common to ignore the subject ("저") in a sentence like this. I have placed "이" right before "문장" because otherwise it's supposed to apply to "~님".

It is a little impolite to directly call someone "당신". What is the relationship between you and her? You can call her "선생님" if she is much older than you, if you are learning something from her, or if she is a teacher. If not, I'd suggest you to call her based on her occupation. For example, "변호사님" if she is a lawyer, "매니저님" if she has a position entitled "manager", etc., but there are some exceptions (e.g. call her "선생님" instead of "교사님" even if she is a "교사").

Comment: Was my first attempt also grammatically correct?

Comment: @user8469759 In your first sentence, I'd strongly suggest to replace "해 와요" with "해 왔어요". It is hard to infer the intended meaning of "생각해 와요" and the sentence is very much likely misinterpreted differently (e.g. as "I think about the sentence you wrote before coming to you"). It will be better to ignore "저는", unless your words follow someone else's and you have to emphasize that what you say applies to you. But with "저는" the sentence is still correct, if you ask.

Comment: For "이 당신이 쓴 문장", the correct order will be "당신이 쓴 이 문장". Depending on your relationship with the listener, you may have to replace "쓴" with the more polite form "쓰신".